# Effective action for ferromagnetism and ferroelectricity

Tags: electromagnetism, lagrangian-formalism, material-science, action, effective-field-theory

In [Three Lectures On Topological Phases Of Matter](https://arxiv.org/abs/1510.07698) section 2.1 mentioned, that:
$$
I^\prime = \int dt d^3x \; \left(\vec{a}\vec{E}+\vec{b}\vec{B}\right)
$$
correspond to **ferromagnetism and ferroelectricity**. And that
$$
I^{\prime\prime} = \int dt d^3x \; \left(a_{ij}E^iE^j+b_{ij}B^iB^j\right)
$$
correspondence to **electric and magnetic susceptibility**.

Could somebody clarify, why? I will be very appreciate for answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The energy of an electric dipole moment $\bf{p}$/magnetic dipole moment $\bf{m}$ in the external field is proportional to it, $W = -\bf{p\cdot E}$ or $W = -\bf{m\cdot B}$. In a ferromagnetic sample the local magnetic dipole moment is propotional to element of volume $d^3x$. This is just the same as you have in the expression for $I'$.

Then, if you consider a dielectric or diamagnetic sample, it gets polarized in the external electric or magnetic field. The susceptibility is a tensor that relates, for example, the dipole moment of unit volume $\bf{P}$ (polarization) and the external field $\bf{E}$: $$P^i=a^i_jE^j.$$
Since $\bf{P}$ is again the dipole moment, you get the expression $I''$ for action.

Comment: Thank you for answer! But in this functionals we consider fields as non-dinamical external parameters, so what information one can extract from such actions?

Comment: @Nikita, Well, since this is a cond-mat action, in general you are mostly interested in the properties of your sample. External field is considered only as a condition, such as pressure or temperature, for instance. You can study the position of Fermi surface or density of states in your system..

Comment: What kind of information one can extract from action? Is such object useful for something?

Comment: @Nikita, a classical problem that one can solve given the susceptibility is to determine the magnetic field inside a sample that is placed in some other magnetic field. I am not an expert in magnetism but, of course, this quantity is of big practical use. An example that I can imagine is the determination of magnetic field inside a detector. If you are measuring tracks of charged particles moving in ext. mag. field, you surely need to know the field inside. Then using a kind of expression for Lorenz force one can deduce particle mass/charge.

Comment: Okay, thank you. But I trying to understand, how somebody can to using this action? What is the next step after writing such action? As I understand, varying by $A_\mu$ we can obtain current, as reflection of small change in external field. But can we find something more interesting?